# Adding text widget inside circular box decoration

Tags: flutter, grid-layout

I want to add text inside circular box decoration. I have the following code but it the text is half inside and half outside the circle. How can I tweak it to ensure that the text always stays inside the circle? Also, how can I make the circle big?

```
 child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
    child: Text(
      title,
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 16),
 
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape:BoxShape.circle,
      image: DecorationImage(    
          image: returnImage(id),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop),
        ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Hi There. Post the parent of your Container. You can also share screenshots of what is currently happening. Also need to better explain what you want to achieve differently.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Text` in a `ClipRRect`

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100, // height should be equal to width
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), // half of the width
    image: DecorationImage(),
  ),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), // same as the Container
    child: Text(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I dont think that's the problem that OP is facing.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increase size of container, I suggest you to increase size of parent widget first.

But for proper solution, Please provide parent widget structure.